# Rust trait bounds not satisfied. Either intermediate assignment is necessary, or removal of a Trait implementation

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, traits

I would like to be able to implement a trait for different function signatures, but the compiler gives me strange errors. I have tried to reduce the problem in the following minimal example:

```
trait MyTrait<P> {
    fn trait_method(&self, p: P);
}

impl MyTrait<fn(u32)> for MyStruct {
    fn trait_method(&self, p: fn(u32)) {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl MyTrait<fn(u64)> for MyStruct {
    fn trait_method(&self, p: fn(u64)) {
        todo!()
    }
}

struct MyStruct;

fn test() {
    let my_struct = MyStruct;

    // Gives error:
    // the trait bound `MyStruct: MyTrait<fn(u32) {test_fun}>` is not satisfied
    //      the following implementations were found:
    //  <MyStruct as MyTrait<fn(u32)>>
    //  <MyStruct as MyTrait<fn(u64)>>
    my_struct.trait_method(test_fun);

    // Is ok
    let fun: fn(u32) = test_fun;
    my_struct.trait_method(fun);

    // Gives error
    // the trait bound `MyStruct: MyTrait<[closure@src/main.rs:176:28: 176:39]>` is not satisfied
    //      the following implementations were found:
    //  <MyStruct as MyTrait<fn(u32)>>
    //  <MyStruct as MyTrait<fn(u64)>>
    my_struct.trait_method(|hi: u32|{});

    // Is ok
    let fun: fn(u32) = |hi: u32|{};
    my_struct.trait_method(fun);
}

fn test_fun(hi: u32) {}
```

If I remove the `impl MyTrait<fn(u64)>` block, then the problem just dissapears, and I can use either way of calling the Trait function. Only when I have multiple implementations of the same trait do these errors occur.

Why is this Rust code incorrect, and what would be a way in which I could fix this? It is quite important to me that it is callable without an intermediate assignmment, since this trait will end up in the public API.

Thanks in advance

edit:
The following code works as well:

```
my_struct.trait_method(test_fun as fn(u32));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I managed to find a way around this problem:

```
pub trait VarFunc<A, P, R, T> {}

impl<F, A: Actor, P, R> VarFunc<A, P, R, WithState> for F where
    F: Fn(&mut A, &mut State<A>, P) -> Flow<A, R>
{
}

impl<F, A: Actor, P, R> VarFunc<A, P, R, WithoutState> for F where
    F: Fn(&mut A, P) -> Flow<A, R>
{
}

pub struct WithState;
pub struct WithoutState;
```

Basically, I have created a new trait `VarFunc`, which can be implemented both `WithState` and `WithoutState`. Then, when specifying the Trait impl, instead of using `F: Fn(X) -> Y`, we use `F: VarFunc<StateX/StateY>`, which can actually be seen as different by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Let's compare this:

```
let fun: fn(u32) = test_fun;
```

and this:

```
let fun = test_fun;
```

The type of `fun` in the first example is explicitly set to `fn(u32)`, whereas in the second version it's actually `fn(u32) {test_fun}`. Those are two different types. The first one is a *function pointer*. The second one is a *function item*. When you explicitly specify the type of `fun`, what happens is known as *coercion*.

Comment: Okay, so I should coerce the function to the proper type, which is not the same, this makes sense.

Why then does my code compile properly if I remove one of the Trait implementations? All the sudden the function gets coerced by itself, without having to do it explicitly. Is there any reason why this happens?  

And then the next question would be if there is any way to fix this code to also make it work with multiple Trait implementations?

Comment: @JaspervanderWerf I don't know. It seems to me the Rust compiler simply "tries harder" to coerce when there is only one trait implementations. That might be on purpose or not.    I'm not sure.